# Updating whole Document if already exist with mongodbDriver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, insert-update

I am using mongodb driver, insert worked with no problem, but that will lead me with multiple documents with the same ID.

What I´m trying to do it´s to use UpdateOne with upsert, to update my document if the ID is found, or just insert if there´s no found ID.

I´m working with MongoDB.Driver 2.8.1, using NET framework 4.5, I read some documentation an examples in differents forums about my issue but can´t fix it.

Here´s the part of the code where I´m having problems.

```
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(getMongoConect());
            var database = client.GetDatabase("Example");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Data");
            var upsert = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

            var variables = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"op_id", transaction.ID },
                {"op_box", transaction.Operation},
                {"RegisterDate",transaction.TodayDate },
                {"ProcedureKind",transaction.Procedure},
                {"User",transaction.RegisterUser },
                {"Status", transaction.ProcedureStatus},
                {"Ofice", transaction.OficeNumber }
            };

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("op_id", transaction.ID);
            var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("op_id", transaction.ID);

            var object= collection.Find(filter);

            //Works with no problems, but give me trash at the DB.
            //collection.InsertOne(variables);
            //Trying to update document if op_id exist or insert if not
            collection.UpdateOne(filter,update,upsert);
        }
```

I expect the Collection.UpdateOne to save the whole document if the id is not found and update it if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how i would do it for upserting whole documents. code also shows how to update only certain fields of existing documents.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Data
        {
            [BsonId]
            public ObjectId op_id { get; set; }
            public string op_box { get; set; }
            public string office { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
                                 .GetDatabase("Example")
                                 .GetCollection<Data>("Data");

            var id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

            //use ReplaceOne when you are inserting or updating whole documents
            collection.ReplaceOne(
                d => d.op_id == id,
                new Data
                {
                    op_id = id,
                    op_box = "box",
                    office = "office"
                },
                new UpdateOptions
                {
                    IsUpsert = true
                });

            //use UpdateOne when you need to update only a few properties/fields
            collection.UpdateOne(
                d => d.op_id == id,
                Builders<Data>.Update.Set(d => d.office, "updated office"));
        }
    }
}
```

i've written a [library](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) that simplifies much of this. check it out if you are able to use .net core framework. with it you can simply do `object.Save()` and it'll take care of upserting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just using the incorrect metod, changed it to ReplaceOne with my current structure and it worked with no problem.